# javascript says JSON object property is undefined although it's not

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties, undefined

I have a json-object, which I print to the screen (using alert()-function):

```
alert(object);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Then I want to print the value of the id to the screen:

```
    alert(object["id"]);
```

The result is this:

[image]

As you can see, the value of key "id" is not(!!!) undefined.

What the hell is going on here?!

Comment: Please include only text in your question, not screenshots of text.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like your json object is not really an object, it's a json string. in order to use it as an object you will need to use a deserialization function like `JSON.parse(obj)`. Many frameworks have their own implementation for deserializing a JSON string. 
When you try to do `alert(obj)` with a real object the result would be [object Object] or something like that

Comment: I was about posting the same! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! That was the solution.

Comment: my problem is different but your idea help me to solve this

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON is not parsed, so in order for JavaScript to be able to access it's values you should parse it first as in line 1:

```
var result = JSON.parse(object);
```

After parsing your JSON Object, you can access it's values as following:

```
alert(result.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign that to a `var` and then access it.

```js
var object = {id: "someId"};
console.log(object);
alert(object["id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, object properties can be accessed with . operator or with associative array indexing using `[]`. I.e. object.property is equivalent to `object["property"]`

You can try:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(Object);
alert(obj.id);
```